# Show that the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I've looked up Eisensteins criterion, but I don't understand how to apply it to show that
$ x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible.

Edit: Ok, I see now that Eisensteins criterion does not apply here.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** a quadratic polynomial is reducible over $k$ iff it has a root in $k$.

Comment: Ok. So if I use the quadratic formula to obtain roots that are not in Z/2[x], is that the way to show that it is irreducible?

Comment: Quadratic formula doesn't make sense in $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, since you have to divide by $2$. However, there are only two elements in the field $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ so you don't need to use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 5):

Since the degree of $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ is $\leq 3$, then $f$ is irreducible if and only if $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. (why?)

Well, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the only possible roots are $0$ and $1$. Try them out!

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion can in fact be used over any domain, not just the field $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Huh.  Wikipedia tells me it does generalize to integral domains.  You learn something new every day.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalization

Comment: It does work, but many domains (e.g. fields) just don't have a useful concept of a prime.